DNSMASQ in 22.04
I've upgraded my server system from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 (via 20).
I can't start DNSMASQ
× dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-10-24 14:25:01 UTC; 1min 21s ago

Process: 4175 ExecStartPre=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq checkconfig (code=exited, status=3)
    CPU: 11ms

Oct 24 14:25:01 mail.taid.info systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Oct 24 14:25:01 mail.taid.info systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Oct 24 14:25:01 mail.taid.info systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 24 14:25:01 mail.taid.info systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
From the syslog the failure is
Oct 24 14:25:01 mail dnsmasq[4182]: cannot access /etc/dnsmasq.d/lxd: No such file or directory
I have tried removing and re-installing DNSMASQ and this is the 3rd iteration.
While this is not working I'm getting errors in the package updates "Temporary failure resolving 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com'" that I assume is related to the failure of DNSMASQ to run.
SOLVED: this thread
Netplan DNS disaster
advises:
to resolve this just remove symlink ¯(ツ)/¯
sudo rm /etc/dnsmasq.d/lxd
And restart:
service dnsmasq restart
service dnsmasq status
